# Dell PowerEdge R410 freezing up

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell

A PowerEdge R410 that was working fine for years started freezing up last week. It's running Ubuntu 20.04 and sometimes it will come back. When it did on a most recent freeze, the dmesg log shows the following:

```
[ 328.721635] mgag200 0000:08:00.0: Video card doesn't support cursors with partial transparency.
[ 328.721636] mgag200 0000:08:00.0: Not enabling hardware cursor.
[ 330.005975] rfkill: input handler disabled
[ 410.086320] [UFW BLOCK] IN=em2 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:9e:72:2c:0a:f4:08:08:00 src=192.168.1.85 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=23542 PROTO=2
[ 1530.436833] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[ 1531.445958] Filesystems sync: 1.009 seconds
[ 1531.446160] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 1531.448021] OOM killer disabled.
[ 1531.448021] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 7.007 seconds) done.
[ 1538.455664] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[ 1538.456556] serial 00:06: disabled
[ 1538.456674] serial 00:05: disabled
[ 1538.662938] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: megasas_suspend is called
[ 1538.694420] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: megasas_disable_intr_fusion is called outbound_intr_mask:0x40000009
[ 1898.587538] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: megasas_resume is called
[ 1898.587559] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: Waiting for FW to come to ready state
[ 1898.587564] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: megasas_disable_intr_fusion is called outbound_intr_mask:0x40000009
[ 1898.588634] serial 00:05: activated
[ 1898.589593] serial 00:06: activated
[ 1898.642003] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: FW now in Ready state
[ 1898.642020] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: 63 bit DMA mask and 32 bit consistent mask
[ 1898.642170] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: requested/available msix 5/5
[ 1898.642179] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: Performance mode :Latency
[ 1898.642180] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: FW supports sync cache : No
[ 1898.642181] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: megasas_disable_intr_fusion is called outbound_intr_mask:0x40000009
[ 1898.716630] tg3 0000:04:00.1 em2: Link is down
[ 1898.894009] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: FW provided supportMaxExtLDs: 0 max_lds: 32
[ 1898.894010] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: controller type : iMR(0MB)
[ 1898.894011] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: Online Controller Reset(OCR) : Enabled
[ 1898.894012] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: Secure JBOD support : No
[ 1898.894013] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: NVMe passthru support : No
[ 1898.894014] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: FW provided TM TaskAbort/Reset timeout: 0 secs/0 secs
[ 1898.894015] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: JBOD sequence map support : No
[ 1898.894015] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: PCI Lane Margining support : No
[ 1898.894058] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: megasas_enable_intr_fusion is called outbound_intr_mask:0x40000000
[ 1898.894060] megaraid_sas 0000:03:00.0: JBOD sequence map is disabled megasas_setup_jbod_map 5734
[ 1898.895085] OOM killer enabled.
[ 1898.895086] Restarting tasks ... done.
[ 1898.906316] PM: suspend exit
[ 1898.956501] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[ 1898.966605] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[ 1898.966703] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[ 1898.967442] ata5: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[ 1898.968652] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[ 1898.970417] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[ 1898.972266] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 1902.396143] tg3 0000:04:00.1 em2: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[ 1902.396144] tg3 0000:04:00.1 em2: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[ 1902.396145] tg3 0000:04:00.1 em2: EEE is disabled
```

Any idea how to troubleshoot or other suggestions?

Comment: Typically Dell server have a hardware event log in their BIOS that e.g. contains ECC RAM errors and other failure messages. In case of problems that would be the first log to check.

Comment: agree go to bios and use the hw diagnostic, this is how the dell support would also ask first.